# CordaApp Installation

Tags: corda

I see the following statement on `Cordapp` document -

> Each Cordapp is installed at the level of the individual node

In real time, when I create a corda application, should I distribute the application to every network participant, so that cordapp is deployed on all nodes in the network?

If not so, how will initiating flows associate with responding flows?

Comment: If someone can list down cordapp installation procedure it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You'll distribute to all appropriate nodes in then network. Once you've developed your cordapp, you'd simply place the cordapp jar in the `cordapp` folder of your node (probably via jenkins job) and after a node restart, your node should be able to load the new workflows and states present in your cordapp.

Comment: How will this be performed in a real world scenario? Say, in a case where 2 organizations come together to form a network and Org-A creates a CorDapp(C1). Should C1 be installed only in the node owned by Org-A?

Comment: you'd install the `contract-state` jar on all the nodes that you think should have that functionality.